# Is there a sample of displaying a BBM contact list using Cascades on BB10?

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, blackberry-qnx

I have been struggling for a little while to get the contact list from a BBM connected app so that I can choose a contact to work with.

I am using the bb::platform::bbm::ContactService class, but whenever I call contacts() it comes back as null, even when the registration process is completed.

Comment: Hi Doug, would it be possible for you to post some code to illustrate the problem more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

That method returns a list of contacts that have your application installed.  There isn't a way for an application to read all of the user's BBM Contacts.

If you are looking to initiate a chat, you can use the invocation framework to do so and not specify a PIN.  This will bring up the BBM contact picker - listing all BBM Contacts - for the user to select from.

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks for the help.  Firstly, I am only interested in the BBM contacts that already have my app, and I do have all the right permissions.  I have managed to get the basic functionality working now by loading the data into a GroupDataModel class and using that as the dataModel of the ListView, as it looks like Cascades won't support the dataModel using a custom class.  When I get a chance to break the code down, I'll post the answer up here.  The crux of my problem was that I was calling the contactService->contacts() method too early and so it was empty.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to make sure your app has the right permissions? It should have access_pimdomain_contacts.

Comment: Permissions are all fine thanks.  I was just calling the contactService->contacts() before the registration process had fully completed.